# Typeahead ruining old searchbox style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

So i'm using this typeahead script

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js
```

And this is my form

```
<div class="container" id="head">
          <div class="col-md-12" align="center" style="padding-top: 1%">
            <h1><%= image_tag("Logo.png", :class => "logo", :style => "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); border-radius: 50px") %></h1>
            <%= form_tag search_events_path, method: :get do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Artist, Event, Festival or Sports Team", class: "srchFld", id: "search"%>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", id: "submit", class: "srchBtn" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function () {
              return $('#search').typeahead({name: "event", remote: "/events_autocomplete?query=%QUERY"});
            });
          </script>
          <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="name" value=""> -->

        </div>
```

For some reason this is sending my form to look like this

[image: Broken search]

How would i go about fixing this?

more than willing to provide more code.

Its supposed to look like this

[image]

Heres the css i missed

```
/* ================ */
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor a {
  color: #fff;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}

.books-search {
  .twitter-typeahead {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

And my css for the search is this

```
  form > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .srchBtn {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 0 17px;
    background: #1292fd;
    width: 99px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0e7bd6;
    color: #fff;
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .srchBtn:active {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #c0392b;
  }
  .srchBtn:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }

  .srchFld {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 0 17px;
    max-width: 404px;
    width: 40%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
    height: 60px;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .srchFld:focus {
    outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to load any CSS? Other than that, it's rather difficult to say from screenshots alone ...

Comment: I'm using some css, Will share now, Just noticed!!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker There you be :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain it very well. Just a small snippet of HTML and CSS with some screenshots is not really enough to really say anything meaningful about your problem. Maybe someone is willing to read through it and make a *guess* at the problem, but I expect not. And that assumes that the problem is actually in the posted code and not somewhere else! You should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem. Then I or someone else can look at it and fiddle with it and see what the problem is...

Comment: ... Basically, this means copy/pasting as little HTML, CSS, and JS to show the problem. Yeah, I realize this is some work especially if this is a large and/or complicated application, but that's the best way to get meaningful answers... Note that you can create snippets by pressing the button in the toolbar or pressing CTRL+M, or you can use jsfiddle if you prefer.

Comment: Its being nested quite deep, i'd be releasing a lot of sensitive data if i did, However i have narrowed it to be something to do with the script below the form!